# store data without using database in android

Tags: android

i have to make an android application in which i need to download a lot of data from the server which is sent to me via XML. i then need to parse the XML and then display the extracted information.

To avoid making the application slow, i have decided to break my XML down into small parts.. so that i can only call the part that i want, this would limit the information that i am receiving.

My question is once that i have parsed the XML data where do i store it ( except for a db ) until my UI is rendered? On the iPhone there is something called user default where in we can store such information. What would be the equivalent in android?

thank you in advance.

Comment: It sounds like you might be pre-optimising a bit here. So long as you show a wait cursor / activity indicator while you're parsing the data, users tend to be fairly happy with a short wait. It depends on the data size and the frequency with which it's invalidated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use application preferences to store data [as shown here](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-application-preferences/) (if the data is small enough).

Their code sample shows:

```
SharedPreferences gameSettings = getSharedPreferences("MyGamePreferences", MODE_PRIVATE);  
SharedPreferences.Editor prefEditor = gameSettings.edit();  
prefEditor.putString("UserName", "Guest123");  
prefEditor.commit();
```

I wouldn't do this for large datasets but it's a handy place to store data.
This gets removed when the application is removed too.

If you've got a lot of data, I'd suggest [storing it on disk](http://huuah.com/android-writing-and-reading-files/).

Comment: That would depend on your use case, how frequently is the data going to change?

Comment: i am doing lazy loading in listview

Answer (score 3):

Every thing you need should be right here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html. Internal storage is the closest to the iPhone equivalent.

Comment: i was under the notion that using the cache would be the best alternative. what do you think?

Comment: Yeah, that will be fine. Just go with whatever you find most comfortable with, since there are many options available here.

Answer (score 1):

1. You could store it in a file.
2. You could store it in `SharedPreferences`
3. You could use a `ContentProvider` --> not recommended for temporary storage.
4. You could use a SQLiteDB --> I know you said you do not want to use this.